# Workbench Outlines not appearing when rendering animation from command line

Tags: rendering, command-line, workbench-render-engine

The "Outlines" feature of the Workbench render engine *Properties / Render Properties / Options / Outline* provides the expected results when rendering an animation from the UI *Render / Render Animation* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>).

Using the command line (for something like `blender -b myfile.blend -a` with proper paths) on the same file gives a result which seems to completely ignore the outlines.

I tried this with multiple projects and Blender versions 2.80, 2.83, 2.91 & 2.92 alpha on a Linux Mint 19.3 environment, all with the same results.
Searching online for bugs and/or implemented features returned nothing of relevance.

Any information on this? Maybe a setting I might have missed? Or a plug-in interfering?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today, and I found a solution by using the OpenGL render in a python script as such:

```
import bpy

# Most cited way of rendering via python:
#bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
# Produces no outline as by using blender -b myfile.blend -a


# Render with OpenGL:
bpy.ops.render.opengl(animation=True, view_context=False)
# Produces outlines as in the GUI
```

This can be used from a terminal like so:

```
blender myBlenderFile.blend --python myPythonScript.py
```

Note however that I omitted the background flag `-b` due to that OpenGL does not support Blender running in the background. So depending on why you want to render from a terminal this solution might not be valid.

It worked well for me, however. Furthermore, it also resulted in a render speed increase as it seems like it better utilized multiple CPU threads.

"Standard" example where outline doesn't take
[image]

OpenGL example where outline works
[image]